# Modifying formatters in Haskell's formatting library

Tags: haskell, formatting

I'm using Chris Done's [formatting](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/formatting-6.0.0) library (specifically formatting-6.0.0). I'm finding it difficult to construct a `higher order' function which maps a formatter to a list formatter, performing a custom action on the resultant list of Builders:

```
list :: ([Builder] -> Builder) -> Format r (a -> r) -> Format r ([a] -> r)
```

This is desirable because it allows me to embed builder formatting logic in the format string.

As an example, suppose the builder function is simply `mconcat`. Then `format (list mconcat int) [1,2,3]` would yield `"123"`. In practice, I may use a builder function which formats a list as an English list, such that the output for the above input would be `"1, 2 and 3"`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you write some example usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's expand out the [`Format`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/formatting-6.0.0/docs/Formatting-Holey.html#t:Format) types from `list :: ([Builder] -> Builder) -> Format r (a -> r) -> Format r ([a] -> r)`

```
 Format            r     (a -> r) -> Format            r     ([a] -> r)
 Holey  Builder    r     (a -> r) -> Holey  Builder    r     ([a] -> r)
(      (Builder -> r) -> (a -> r))->(      (Builder -> r) -> ([a] -> r))
```

We can try to build the definition of `list`.

```
list append m = Holey $ \k -> ...
```

We need to return an `[a] -> r` where the `...` is. We don't have very many possible moves because we know nothing about the type `r`. We can pass `k :: Builder -> r` to `runHM m` to get an `a -> r`. If we `map` that over the `[a]` we have a `[r]`, but we know nothing about `r`, so we can't do anything with it.

If a function like `list` exists it has a different type than `([Builder] -> Builder) -> Format r (a -> r) -> Format r ([a] -> r)`.

---

We can define `list` with a different type `list :: ([Builder] -> Builder) -> Format Builder (a -> Builder) -> Format r ([a] -> r)`. This should work for most first arguments since most of the formatting components are universally qualified over all `r`.

```
list append m = Holey $ \k -> k . append . map (runHM m id)
```

This can be written more succinctly as

```
list append m = later (append . map (bprint m))
```

Comment: Thank you, your reasoning makes a lot of sense. I've found the Holey type to be slightly complicated so I was wondering if I was missing something. Anyway, you're right that the type of the list combinator you suggest is general enough to work with the rest of the library, so I'll use that.